# Java EE TCP Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tcp

I'm developing a web application in Java EE/Spring/SpringWEB.

A part of the application needs to communicate with mobile devices through TCP/UDP (not HTTP). I want that all infrastructure runs in the Java EE container (Tomcat for instance). I wonder whether there's any standard or part of the Java EE container (Tomcat) I can reuse for having a TCP Server for free?

I mean I do not want to implement my own TCP server which needs to be scalable/reliable and efficent. I want to reuse as much as possible and use standards where applicable.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything in Java EE, not sure about Spring. For implementing on your own, I would highly recommend using [netty](http://netty.io/) as the main building block for your tcp server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Tomcat is not a true Java EE server, but rather the web servlet part of the Java EE stack. There is no real official TCP server lib included in Java EE, except the Java SE socket libraries. I suggest you use the open source library [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/) for TCP/UDP server features. It should work with Tomcat. A full Java EE stack (glassfish, websphere, weblogic, geronimo..) might disallow setting up TCP listeners, so be careful if you migrate from Tomcat to a full java ee stack.